# How to use cakephp collections function in a complex array, it only works on simple ones

Tags: php, json, cakephp-3.0

I transformed an XML to JSON, this is the link:
https://api.myjson.com/bins/us5f4

I used a lot of CakePHP 3.30 and below Collection's functions.
What I need to do is to only extract some data, for example the tag @INDICATOR and @TIME_PERIOD.

I already tried using nest, filter, append, map in collections and none of them work for some reason.

This is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Collection\Collection;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Utility\Xml;

class BalancesFiscalesController extends AppController
{public function balancesDatos2(){
        $xmlArray = Xml::toArray(Xml::build('webroot/e-ggds/BalanceFiscalGC.xml'));


                    $collection = new Collection($xmlArray);
                    $collection->nest('@INDICATOR', '[]')->toList(); //I tried with the parent "Series" still same problem. It returns me the whole JSON instead of what I need. I also tried filter, map, append, no luck.

        //Gobierno Central
        $response = [
            'gob_central' =>[
                    'titulos' =>[
                        $collection
                    ]
                    ]
            ];


           $this->set([
            'data' => $response,
            '_serialize' => ['data']
              ]);

    }

}
```

Comment: So, you want to extract just the `@INDICATOR` values? Like, your result would be `["PAN_CGO_GCRG_XDC", "PAN_CGO_GCRGRC_XDC", "PAN_CGO_GCRGRT_XDC", ...]`?

Comment: exactly @greg-schmidt  I read the collections document and still do not understand how to do it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract a field from a collection, you'd use the [`extract`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::extract) function. Assuming that it's all under the `[data][gob_central][titulos][0][StructureSpecificData][message:DataSet][Series]` key, it might look like this:

```
$series = $xmlArray['data']['gob_central']['titulos'][0]['StructureSpecificData']['message:DataSet']['Series'];
$data = collection($series)->extract('@INDICATOR')->toArray();
```

If there might be multiple items in the `titulos` key, then maybe more like this:

```
$titulos = $xmlArray['data']['gob_central']['titulos'];
$data = collection($titulos)->extract('StructureSpecificData.message:DataSet.Series.{*}.@INDICATOR')->toArray();
```

Comment: Holy COW !! it was that simple, thank you so much Greg it worked perfectly.